# How to send data from a button click to a controller in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to send the id data from a button back to one of my controllers on button click.  Depending on the id sent, I want the controller function to redirect the user to different views.

Button:

```
<a href="/oauth/facebook" id="{{$artist->id}}" class="sign">
```

/oauth/facebook route:

```
Route::get('oauth/{provider}', 'Oauth2Controller@action_session')->before('guest');
```

Function action_session in Oauth2Controller:

```
public function action_session($provider) {

        $id=Input::get('id');

        if($id > 5) {
                return Redirect::to('/fans');
                }
                else {
                return Redirect::to('/artists');
                }
}
```

I tried using ajax but it seems that the oauth/facebook route is called on button click first, before the ajax request can go through (so the $id field is blank when the controller runs).  Is there any way to do this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't find the id in the input using this approach, but you could extend the route with an optional (unless you want it for all providers) parameter like this:

Route

```
Route::get('oauth/{provider}/{id?}', 'Oauth2Controller@action_session')->before('guest');
```

Controller

```
public function action_session($provider, $id = null) {

    if ($id > 5) {
        return Redirect::to('fans');
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('artists');
    }
}
```

Button

```
<a href="/oauth/facebook/{{$artist->id}}" class="sign">...</a>
```

Comment: Would you need to provide an id in order for oauth/facebook to run the action_session function?